# How can get an exact copy of my PC into another PC?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-transfer

Lets say I have computer A running ubuntu and I've downloaded several apps, changed the template to make it look nice stored tons of documents, code, photos, any file and set up specific commands for my keyboard to do stuff.

Now lets say I have computer B running a non-linux OS and I go and install kubuntu with my usb-installer. Is there a way to, after installing kubuntu, copy *everything* from computer A to computer B?

By *everything* I mean every app, configuration, hotkeys, layout, you name it; all kind of stuff that are not files that I could have in an external hard drive and just download from there.

Comment: Are you wanting to overwrite the data on computer B with the data on computer A?   Also, is saying that computer A and computer B have very similar hardware or generic hardware reasonable here?

Comment: Yes, I want to overwrite the data on computer B. In my particular case, no. what I'm running right now (computer A) is a 2009 tower PC with kubuntu init, and computer B would be a 2012 mac osx or a new 2020 windows PC. Basically, from computer A to another machine no matter what hardware differences they have

Comment: No one can answer this question definitively.  Computer B's OS is not important - but the chipsets and built-in OS support is.  Ubuntu has good support for a wide range of hardware, so its quite practical to do a bitcopy of a disk as long as disk A is not larger then Disk B.  There may or may not be driver issues related to graphics cards and NICS, but doing this for servers is fairly common.

Comment: what is the proper way of googling that? 'disk bitcopy'? never done this before hence don't know where to look properly

Comment: There is no one answer. The problem is nuanced and you have not adequately described it. ddrescue and dd are common ways of bitcopying a disk, but far from the only ways. Yes, "bitcopy block device" might be a good google search term.